# Is it guaranteed that a linear programming problem has a unique solution?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Given a generic linear programming problem i.e.

- minimize $\hat C^T \hat X$
- subject to $\hat A \hat X \leq \hat B$
- and $\hat X \geq 0$

Is it guaranteed (mathematically speaking) that a solution exists? I'm inclined to say yes (just as a raw guess withouth any thought), but is there a proof of this?

Comment: Consider low-dimensional problems.  Draw a picture of the constraints and the objective function.  The answer ought to become evident.  If it isn't, contemplate the one-dimensional case where the constraints are $x \le -1$ and $x \gt 0.$

Comment: Do you see this as a question about *statistics*? I wonder if this would be better migrated to the [mathematics.SE] SE site, or some other more specialized site like [cstheory.SE].

Answer (score 2):

The [link](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~angelia/L5_exist_optimality.pdf) here lays out the requirements for the optimal solution to exist. If the constraint region is convex and nonempty than we are guaranteed to find a solution at one of the vertices. The convexity of constraint region is key for the solution, so the solution for your setup will always exist when $\hat{A}\hat{X}=\hat{B}$ has non-negative solutions.

EDIT:
There exist some cases when the feasible region is open, and in those cases a solution does not exist because of unboundedness (especially for cases when $\hat{A}\hat{X}>\hat{B}$. A nice discussion about the unique solution of LP can be found [here](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379579900144/1-s2.0-0024379579900144-main.pdf?_tid=aee9362b-7206-4d33-aac8-34df459a8e69&acdnat=1534579563_e17435c18f17d3a45390ecc325baf1da)

Comment: You forgot the most crucial condition: the constraint region has to be nonempty.  (Empty regions are convex.)

Comment: Yes, I forgot that condition. Editing the answer right now to reflect that.

Comment: You've also left out the possibility that the LP could be unbounded and have no optimal solution.  You haven't discussed uniqueness questions either.

Comment: Thanks. Editing the answer to reflect the unboundedness. I forgot to include uniqueness too.